# Trouble findingElement, more complex than a basic xpath, id, or class case

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[find 3rd td in tr where class contains zebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zh1mp.png)

The photo shows what I'm working with. For each of the 4 animals, I need to select the associated quantity (which is always the 3rd td in the tr). In the html below, you can see zebra has quantity 1, and lion has quantity 1.

I have been unsuccessful finding by class. Maybe you tell me why. Is it because of the space in the string?

A simple xpath won't work because the tr tags change depending on user inputs on the prior page.

I've also tried to select by xpath with contains method to no avail. Maybe I'm just not doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot use className locator when there is a space in the Name instead you have to use cssselector or xpath.

```
    // css selector
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".line_item.Zebra"));
   //xpath should also work 
    driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='line_item Zebra']"));
```

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted, but it doesn't show b/c my account is new.

Answer (score 0):

`line_item Zebra` are two classes of the same `WebElement`. You can find by `className` only with one of them

```
driver.findElement(By.className("Zebra"));
```

If you want all the animals you can use `line_item` class. That will give you all the animals

```
List<WebElement> animals = driver.findElements(By.className("line_item"));
```

`animals` now holds list of the four elements with class `line_item`. To get the third `<td>` in each one you can use the `WebElements` in the list

```
for (WebElement animal : animals) {
    List<WebElement> tds = animal.findElements(By.tagNmae("td")); // all the <td> tags in that animal
    String quantity = tds.get(2).getText(); // get the text of the third <td>
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted, but it doesn't show b/c my account is new.